# How to change Color of the Card widget in flutter when is clicked (Multiple Time)?

Tags: flutter

I want to change The Color of a card So when I click  once the color change to Blue and when I click again I want to change the color to default ?
Some thing like this :

```
 Color color;
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  color = Colors.transparent;
   }

InkWell(
   onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
    });
  },

  child:Card(
  color:color
  )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that without using 'color'

```
 bool activeColor = false;
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
   }

InkWell(
   onTap: () {
    activeColor = !activeColor;
  },

  child:Card(
  color: activeColor ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.transparent,
  )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you ? you saved my Life hhh ^^ ?